# Encountered server error when trying to parse date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I have coded logic where in I am importing data from CSV to Google Spreadsheet. As a next step I am trying to push the copied data to Cloud SQL instance using JDBC service. I have one column which is of type `DateTime`(in backend). in logic which will push data from spreadhseet  to Cloud SQL I am using `Jdbc.parseDate()` method to convert the value in spreadsheet to Mysql /Cloud SQL.

ex: `stmt.setDate(counter, Jdbc.parseDate(colValue));`

*Where:*

1. counter is index and
2. colValue is the value under the column in Google Spreadsheet

In am attempt to do so, i get error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

I did not get any error otherwise, not even when i use

```
stmt.setDate(counter, Jdbc.newDate(colValue));
```

Please advise how this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the code that worked for me is:

// Iterate through the spreadsheet records,

```
var tempDate = Utilities.formatDate(colValue, "IST",  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
stmt.setObject(counter, tempDate);
```

**Where:**

- colValue: is the value of the column reading from spreadsheet
- counter: is the index, where I have to insert value

Using above code I was able to read the date from spreadsheet and insert it in column(of DateTime type) of table in cloud SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be an issue of type confusion. `Jdbc.newDate()` expects an integer as the argument. You are possibly providing a date object (depending on how the data is stored in your spreadsheet).

Assuming you are storing the object as a date in the spreadsheet, you can try to fix this by using `Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime())`.

Comment: My intention is to parse date. The date is displayed as "9/8/2012 9:21:09" in Spreadsheet. When I read spreadsheet's data using apps script i see(view logs) date as" Sat Sep 08 2012 09:21:09 GMT+0530 (IST)" in logs. So before pushing data to backend, i am trying to convert date using method  Jdbc.parseDate(colValue). This is where i get error.

Comment: This is because the Spreadsheet is providing the value to you as a javascript Date object. Did you try the code I provided? `Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime())`?

Comment: On doing this, 
var dt = Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime());
I get output = Date.
On executing below logger,
Logger.log("test::"+dt.getTime());
Output that i get is Date and Time in Epoch Format.

I want Columns data to be pushed to Cloud SQL. Please advise how to achieve that.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with `Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime())`. Could you please be more clear? It constructs a JdbcDate using the value from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Its correct that it construct a Date out of Spreadsheet value but then it gives date in Epoch format. 
As requirement is to read and then insert date to Cloud SQL. So if I use Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime())I will get data in Epoch format. Is there way to get the date in the format which is compatible with DB and can directly be pushed to DB.

Comment: Yes. `colValue.getTime()` will return the number of [milliseconds since Jan 1 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). If you look at the argument for `Jdbc.newDate()`, it requires the number of milliseconds.

Comment: I tried Jdbc.newDate(colValue.getTime()) but then it inserts only date in database. I wanted to insert date along with time. Further, i tried Jdbc.newTimestamp(colValue.getTime()) and this time, date and time both were inserted in database. But not sure where and how to modify the time zone .

Comment: That is correct. Jdbc.newDate() is just a month/day/year. Jdbc.newTimestamp() is a date and time.